# Does an AC circuit transmitting 20hz and 2khz audio frequency carry twice as much energy as a 40hz and 4khz frequency?

Tags: energy-conservation, electromagnetic-induction

If a guitar pickup uses electromagnetic induction to induce AC current into a wire, does the low fundamental frequencies in that current carry more energy than the higher frequencies?

This is not a homework question, I am solving only life problems :)

Comment: Why do you think it would? (Asking because if we understand your reasoning, we can give you a better answer)

Comment: @ThePhoton because when it is in the DAW the low frequencies do carry more information, but I don't know about before it hits the speakers, or whether a piezo sensor considers lower frequencies to be more energy in an AC circuit etc